# Display data from Database with class and DAO

Tags: php, mysql, class, dao

I actually code in PHP a class and a DAO class like this : 
dbDAO content only my database PDO connection. I want, to display on my index page, all my product that my database contains. What is the best method to display all my products from my database, is it in my DAO Class or by using an object Product? DAO class is for modify only content in my database ?

Here's my code :

**DAO Class :**

```
class ProduitDao extends dbDAO
{
  public function displayProduits()
  {
      $product = $this->bdd->prepare("SELECT * FROM products");
      $product->execute();

      while ($displayProduct = $product->fetch() )
      {
        ?>
        <div class="prodname">
          <?php
          echo '<a href="./product.php?id='.$displayProduct['no'].'"</a>';
          echo '<img src="images/produits/'.$displayProduct['image'].'" alt=" '.$affichageProduit['nom'].' "</img>';
          ?>
        </div>
        <?php
      }
  }
```

**Product class :**

```
    public function __construct($no, $img)
    {
         $this->no = $numero;
         $this->img = $img;
    }

// GET and SET goes here
```

Tancks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Never ever ever combine HTML (presentation logic) with your business logic.

What you might want to do is:

Define your entities (Plain PHP Object) that define the data.

```
class ProductEntity {
     protected id;
     protected name;
     //then define your setters and getters
}
```

Then you'll have your DAO to return the entity you just defined.

```
class ProductDao {
    public function getProducts() {
        $products = [];
        $product = $this->bdd->prepare("SELECT * FROM products");
        $product->execute();

        while ($displayProduct = $product->fetch()) {
             $p = new Product();
             $p->setId($displayProduct['id']);
             $p->setName($displayProduct['name']);
             $products[] = $p;
        }
        return products;
    }
}
```

Now you can call your DAO to return a collection of Products.

And then you'd pass this collection to a VIEW layer, and this is where you can add HTML (Presentation Logic)

```
foreach ($products as $product) {
    echo '<div>' . $product->getId() . '</div>';
}
```

Comment: I see now! Tancks for the help! :)

Comment: "Define your entities (Plain PHP Object)" called Model also...